Unreal 5 : How to bind RPC Function to Enhanced Input?
i tried to make movement functions with RPC.
And the movement functions, is binded with EnhancedInput->BindAction.
void AGoKartPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Setup Player Input Component"));

    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    UEnhancedInputComponent* EnhancedInput = Cast<UEnhancedInputComponent>(InputComponent);
    if (EnhancedInput == nullptr) return;

    EnhancedInput->BindAction(AccelerateAction, ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &AGoKartPawn::Server_Accelerate);
    EnhancedInput->BindAction(AccelerateAction, ETriggerEvent::Completed, this, &AGoKartPawn::ClearAccelerate);

    EnhancedInput->BindAction(TurnAction, ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &AGoKartPawn::TurnRight);
    EnhancedInput->BindAction(TurnAction, ETriggerEvent::Completed, this, &AGoKartPawn::ClearTurning);
}

As i want to make it multiplay game, i did declared Accelerate function as RPC.
    UFUNCTION(Server, Reliable, WithValidation)
    void Server_Accelerate(const FInputActionValue& Value);

So there are Implement and Validate functions.
void AGoKartPawn::Server_Accelerate_Implementation(const FInputActionValue& Value)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Accelerating"));
    // 1 or 0
    float IsAccelerating = Value.Get<float>();
    Accelerating = IsAccelerating;
}

bool AGoKartPawn::Server_Accelerate_Validate(const FInputActionValue& Value)
{
    return FMath::Abs(Value.Get<float>()) <= 1;
}

But the problem is, server pawn's movement is fine but client pawn doesn't move at all both on server and client.
I expected that after the player input keys, client pawn move upon the server's movement decision by the RPC movement function based on such key input.
But I can't find any other references like using RPC in Enhanced Input.
if there are other ways to Enhanced Input System can multiplay, please let me know.
Thanks for your help :D

Any particular reason you're not relaying the Movement logic to a PawnMovementComponent (either custom or something like the VehicleMovementComponent)? What is your "accelerating" variable doing? Where is it set or used? I don't see any logic that would cause the cart to move here.
